Flutter Sudoku App From Loadstate Userfilled numbers is been displayed but not updated in the table cell
"When loading user-filled numbers into my Sudoku table using SharedPreferences, the issue arises where the number is displayed in the cell from the loaded state, but it is not updated within the cell. I have to click on that cell, and then update the number for it to be reflected."
class PausePlay extends StatefulWidget {
  const PausePlay({required this.difficulty, super.key});
// ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  final difficulty;

  @override
  State<PausePlay> createState() => _PausePlayState();
}

class _PausePlayState extends State<PausePlay> {
  final SudokuPoints _pointsManager = SudokuPoints();

  late List<List<int?>> _userFilledNumbers =
      List.generate(9, (_) => List<int?>.filled(9, null));

  late GlobalKey _repaintKey;
  late List<List<int?>> _sudokuGrid;
  late List<List<bool>> _userFilled;
  late List<List<List<int?>>> _userPencilMarks;
  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> _moveHistory;
  late List<int> _remainingNumbers;
  late Timer _timer;

  int? _selectedNumber;
  int? _selectedRow;
  int? _selectedCol;

  int _remainingHints = 3;
  int _mistakeCount = 0;
  int _secondsElapsed = 0;

  bool _isPencilActivated = false;
  bool _isPaused = false;

  bool _isGameWon() {
    return SudokuValidator(_sudokuGrid).isSudokuSolved();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initializeState();

    _startTimer();
    _loadGameState();
    _repaintKey = GlobalKey();
  }

  void _loadGameState() async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> gameState = await GameStateManager.loadGameState();
      List<List<bool>> userFilled = await GameStateManager.loadUserFilled();
      List<List<int?>> userFilledNumbers =
          await GameStateManager.loadUserFilledNumbers();
      List<List<List<int?>>> userPencilMarks =
          await GameStateManager.loadUserPencilMarks();

      List<List<int?>> sudokuGrid = await GameStateManager.loadTableState();

      setState(() {
        _remainingHints = gameState['remainingHints'];
        _mistakeCount = gameState['mistakeCount'];
        _secondsElapsed = gameState['secondsElapsed'];
        _userFilled = userFilled;
        _userFilledNumbers = userFilledNumbers;
        _userPencilMarks = userPencilMarks;
        _sudokuGrid = sudokuGrid;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error loading game state: $e');
    }
  }

  void _handleGameWon() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WinPage(
          totalTime: _formatTime(_secondsElapsed),
          difficultys: widget.difficulty,
          points: _pointsManager.points,
        );
      },
    ).then((_) async {
      if (_isGameWon()) {
        try {
          RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = _repaintKey.currentContext!
              .findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
          ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
          ByteData? byteData =
              await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

          if (byteData != null) {
            Uint8List screenshot = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
            FirebaseManager.uploadGameResult(
              secondsElapsed: _secondsElapsed,
              difficulty: widget.difficulty,
              points: _pointsManager.points,
              mistakeCount: _mistakeCount,
              imageData: screenshot,
            );
          }
        } catch (e) {
          debugPrint('Error capturing and uploading screenshot: $e');
        }
      }
    });
    GameStateManager.deleteGameState();
  }

  void _initializeState() {
    _sudokuGrid = List.generate(9, (_) => List<int?>.filled(9, null));
    _userFilled = List.generate(9, (_) => List<bool>.filled(9, false));
    _userFilledNumbers = List.generate(9, (_) => List<int?>.filled(9, null));
    _userPencilMarks = List.generate(9, (_) => List.generate(9, (_) => []));
    _moveHistory = [];
    _remainingNumbers = List<int>.generate(9, (_) => 9);
  }

  void _togglePause() {
    setState(() {
      _isPaused = !_isPaused;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _timer.cancel();
    GameStateManager.saveGameState(
      difficulty: widget.difficulty,
      remainingHints: _remainingHints,
      mistakeCount: _mistakeCount,
      secondsElapsed: _secondsElapsed,
    );
    GameStateManager.saveUserFilledNumbers(
        userFilledNumbers: _userFilledNumbers);
    GameStateManager.saveUserPencilMarks(userPencilMarks: _userPencilMarks);
  }

// Start the timer
  void _startTimer() {
    const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    _timer = Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer timer) {
      setState(() {
        if (!_isPaused) {
          _secondsElapsed++;
        }
      });
    });
  }

//time format
  String _formatTime(int seconds) {
    int minutes = seconds ~/ 60;
    int remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    String minutesStr = minutes < 10 ? '0$minutes' : '$minutes';
    String secondsStr =
        remainingSeconds < 10 ? '0$remainingSeconds' : '$remainingSeconds';
    return '$minutesStr:$secondsStr';
  }

//undo
  void _handleUndo() {
    if (_moveHistory.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        final lastMove = _moveHistory.removeLast();
        final row = lastMove['row'];
        final col = lastMove['col'];
        final prevValue = lastMove['prevValue'];

        _sudokuGrid[row][col] = prevValue;
        _userFilled[row][col] = prevValue == null ? false : true;

        _calculateRemainingNumbers();
      });
    }
  }

//eraser
  void _handleEraser() {
    SudokuFunctions.eraser(
        _sudokuGrid, _userFilled, _selectedRow, _selectedCol);
    setState(() {
      _calculateRemainingNumbers();
    });
  }

//Pencil
  void handlePencil(int number) {
    if (_selectedRow != null && _selectedCol != null) {
      setState(() {
// Toggle the number as a pencil mark in the cell
        if (_userPencilMarks[_selectedRow!][_selectedCol!].contains(number)) {
          _userPencilMarks[_selectedRow!][_selectedCol!].remove(number);
        } else {
          _userPencilMarks[_selectedRow!][_selectedCol!].add(number);
        }

        _selectedNumber = null;
      });
    }
  }

//hintt
  void _handleHint(BuildContext context) {
    if (_remainingHints > 0) {
      SudokuFunctions.hint(_sudokuGrid, _userFilled, context,
          (int row, int col, int number) {
        setState(() {
          _remainingHints--;
          _sudokuGrid[row][col] = number;
          _userFilled[row][col] = false;
          _userFilledNumbers[row][col] = number;
        });
      });
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('No more hints available!'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  void _calculateRemainingNumbers() {
    _remainingNumbers = List<int>.generate(9, (_) => 9);

    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
        if (_sudokuGrid[row][col] != null) {
          _remainingNumbers[_sudokuGrid[row][col]! - 1]--;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Widget _numTiles(BuildContext context, int index) {
    int row = index ~/ 9;
    int col = index % 9;
    int? value = _sudokuGrid[row][col];

    bool isSelected = _selectedRow != null &&
        _selectedCol != null &&
        (_selectedRow == row || _selectedCol == col);

    bool isInSelectedSubgrid = _selectedRow != null &&
        _selectedCol != null &&
        _isInSelectedSubgrid(row, col);

    bool isEditable = value == null || _userFilled[row][col];

    bool isWrongNumber = _userFilled[row][col] &&
        value != null &&
        !SudokuValidator(_sudokuGrid).isValidPlacement(row, col, value);

    bool hasUserPencilMarks = _userPencilMarks[row][col].isNotEmpty;

    Color? cellColor = isWrongNumber
        ? Colors.redAccent
        : isSelected || isInSelectedSubgrid
            ? Colors.deepPurple[100]
            : Colors.white;

    Color? textColor = isWrongNumber
        ? Colors.white
        : isSelected || isInSelectedSubgrid
            ? Colors.black
            : isEditable
                ? Colors.deepPurple[800]
                : Colors.black;

    if (_selectedRow == row && _selectedCol == col) {
      cellColor = Colors.deepPurpleAccent[100];
      textColor = Colors.white;
    }

    if (_selectedNumber != null && value == _selectedNumber) {
      cellColor = Colors.deepPurple[400];
      textColor = Colors.white;
    }

    if (!isEditable && hasUserPencilMarks) {
      _userPencilMarks[row][col] = [];
    }

    if (_userFilledNumbers[row][col] != null) {
      value = _userFilledNumbers[row][col];
      textColor = Colors.deepPurpleAccent;
    }

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: isEditable
          ? () {
              setState(() {
                _selectedRow = row;
                _selectedCol = col;
                _selectedNumber = value;
              });
            }
          : null,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            top: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
              width: _getBorderWidth(row, true),
            ),
            left: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
              width: _getBorderWidth(col, false),
            ),
            right: col == 8
                ? const BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent, width: 1.0)
                : BorderSide.none,
            bottom: row == 8
                ? const BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent, width: 1.0)
                : BorderSide.none,
          ),
          color: cellColor,
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Text(
                '${value ?? ''}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: textColor,
                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsBold',
                  fontSize: 22,
                  fontWeight:
                      isWrongNumber ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (isEditable && hasUserPencilMarks) _buildPencilMarks(row, col),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPencilMarks(int row, int col) {
    bool isSelected = _selectedRow != null &&
        _selectedCol != null &&
        (_selectedRow == row || _selectedCol == col);
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            int number = index + 1;
            bool isUserPencil = _userPencilMarks[row][col].contains(number);
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                isUserPencil ? '$number' : '',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 10,
                  color: isSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                  fontFamily: 'PoppinsBold',
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: 9,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  double _getBorderWidth(int position, bool isRow) {
    if ((position % 3 == 0 && position > 0)) {
      return 2.5;
    }
    return 1.0;
  }

  bool _isInSelectedSubgrid(int row, int col) {
    if (_selectedRow == null || _selectedCol == null) {
      return false;
    }

    int subgridStartRow = (_selectedRow! ~/ 3) * 3;
    int subgridStartCol = (_selectedCol! ~/ 3) * 3;

    return row >= subgridStartRow &&
        row < subgridStartRow + 3 &&
        col >= subgridStartCol &&
        col < subgridStartCol + 3;
  }

  void _updateCell(int number) async {
    if (_selectedRow != null && _selectedCol != null) {
      bool isValid = await SudokuValidator(_sudokuGrid)
          .validateCell(_selectedRow!, _selectedCol!, number);

      if (isValid) {
        _pointsManager.correctMove(); // Increment points for correct move
      } else {
        _pointsManager.wrongMove(); // Decrement points for wrong move
      }

      if (isValid) {
        _moveHistory.add({
          'row': _selectedRow!,
          'col': _selectedCol!,
          'prevValue': _sudokuGrid[_selectedRow!][_selectedCol!],
        });
      } else {
        _moveHistory.add({
          'row': _selectedRow!,
          'col': _selectedCol!,
          'prevValue': _sudokuGrid[_selectedRow!][_selectedCol!],
        });

        setState(() {
          _mistakeCount++;
        });
      }

      setState(() {
        if (isValid) {
          _sudokuGrid[_selectedRow!][_selectedCol!] = number;
          _userFilled[_selectedRow!][_selectedCol!] = false;
          _userFilledNumbers[_selectedRow!][_selectedCol!] = number;
        } else {
          _sudokuGrid[_selectedRow!][_selectedCol!] = number;
          _userFilled[_selectedRow!][_selectedCol!] = true;
          _userFilledNumbers[_selectedRow!][_selectedCol!] = null;
        }

        _selectedRow = null;
        _selectedCol = null;
        _selectedNumber = null;
        _calculateRemainingNumbers();

        if (_isGameWon()) {
          _handleGameWon();
          _timer.cancel();
        }
      });

      if (!isValid) {
        // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Wrong Sudoku move!'),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }

  void _updateSelectedNumber(int number) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedNumber = _selectedNumber == number ? null : number;
    });
  }

  Widget _numberButton(int number) {
    return NumberButton(
      number: number,
      isPencilActivated: _isPencilActivated,
      selectedNumber: _selectedNumber,
      remainingNumbers: _remainingNumbers,
      handlePencil: handlePencil,
      updateSelectedNumber: _updateSelectedNumber,
      updateCell: _updateCell,
    );
  }

I need from loadstate the userfilled number should be updated inside the cell instead of displaying it.
